# Sum of lists in recursive functions

Tags: python, list, recursion

I'm trying to make a function in python 3 that counts the number of 1's in a list of 0's and 1's, but it needs to be recursive without using the sum function. Could somebody explain why this function doesn't work?

```
def count_ones(s):
    if len(s) == 0:        
        return 0    
    elif s[0] == 1:       
        return 1 + count_ones(s[1:])   
    elif s[0] == 0:
        return 0 + count_ones(s[1:])
```

When I plug in `count_ones([1, 0, 0, 1, 1])`, I get

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you sure you copied it correctly?

Comment: That works for me too with python 3.4

Answer (score 0):

Your base case needs to handle a single element. So if you have just one element, convert it to `int` and return that value.

```
def count_ones(l):
    if len(l) == 1:
        return int(l[0])     # Return int value 1 or 0
    else:
        return int(l[0]) + count_ones(l[1:])
```

Test

```
>>> count_ones([1,0,0,1,1])
3
```

Comment: Oh I didn't look at it carefully enough then. Hmm based on the code they posted it is impossible for them to have achieved that error with that function.

Comment: This doesn't work for empty lists. It's better to have the empty list as the base case for your recursion.